Update chunk text file with Drive API resumable upload failed with 100000 byte(s) error
I'm using fetch to make a PATCH request like below:
fetch(uri, {
    method: "PATCH",
    headers: new Headers({
         "Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token,
         "Content-Length": 256,
         "Content-Range": `bytes 0-${256-1}/${JSON.stringify({ items }).length}`,
         "Content-Type": "text/plain"
    }),
    body: JSON.stringify({ items }).substring(0, 256),
}).then((res) => {
    return res.json();
})
.then(data => cb(db))
.catch(e => cb(e));

And it gives me a weird error because the bytes of uploaded chunk I want to upload is 256:

UPDATE:
It seems like that resumable URI was used already not working (return status code of 200 and not expired 7 days) I just generate a new request of new resumable URI with same headers it says:

So even the old resumable URI is not expired, it cannot be used to update the existing file.
Is it correct?

Although I'm not sure about your actual situation, in your situation, when you use a new location URL, what result will you obtain?
